# Is there a way for a delegate in a different file to set a variable in a view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

Context:

I have a View Controller whose root view contains a button and a UIImage. When the button is pressed a UIImagePickerController is presented. The delegate for the UIImagePickerController is another class called ImagePickerDelegate. In one of the methods in the ImagePikerDelegate I would like to set the imageView in view controller with the image that the user just picked.

Question:

How can I access the imageView instance variable that is in the ViewController from ImagePickerDelegate?

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickImageItemBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    lazy var imagePickerDelegate: ImagePickerDelegate = ImagePickerDelegate()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // enable pick image button if photo library is available
        pickImageItemBarButton.isEnabled = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary)
    }

    @IBAction func pickAnImage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        // set imagePicker properties
        imagePicker.delegate = imagePickerDelegate
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        // set the source type as photo library
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        // check if public.image is an available mediaType
        if let _ = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: imagePicker.sourceType)?.contains("public.image") {
            // set mediaType
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
            // present imagePicker modally
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

class ImagePickerDelegate: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    // MARK: Delegate Functions
    // cancel imagePicker
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // image picked
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            // ----This is where I need to access imageView from ViewController to set an image ----
        }

        // dismiss the picker modal view
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a solution to my problem. Not sure if it conforms to best practices with delegates though.

I created an instance variable in ImagePickerDelegate that contains the ViewController instance that is hosting the imageView. I also created an initializer for the delegate that asks for the ViewController hosting the image.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickImageItemBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    lazy var imagePickerDelegate: ImagePickerDelegate = ImagePickerDelegate(imageHost: self)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // enable pick image button if photo library is available
        pickImageItemBarButton.isEnabled = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary)
    }

    @IBAction func pickAnImage(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        // set imagePicker properties
        imagePicker.delegate = imagePickerDelegate
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        // set the source type as photo library
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        // check if public.image is an available mediaType
        if let _ = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: imagePicker.sourceType)?.contains("public.image") {
            // set mediaType
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
            // present imagePicker modally
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

class ImagePickerDelegate: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties
    let viewControllerHostingImage: ViewController

    init(imageHost vc: ViewController) {
        self.viewControllerHostingImage = vc
    }

    // MARK: Delegate Functions
    // cancel imagePicker
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // image picked
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            // set image in hosting view controller's imageView
            viewControllerHostingImage.imageView = image
        }

        // dismiss the picker modal view
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```